# AWS SQS JMS Acknowledgement

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, jms, amazon-sqs

I am using default MessageListener for connecting to SQS queue. I want to track and retry for messages which has Exception. So I am using DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode. In this case if I am doing acknowledgement for one message it is acknowledging all the messages in queue.

How do I make each message ack work, and retry for messages with exception?

```
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try{
        //my logic
        message.acknowledge();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT is a lazy acknowledgement mode which acknowledges message in a batch after a certain interval of time has passed since the last batch was acknowledged.

You should use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode if you want to acknowledge each message separately.
Spring message listener with Client_Acknowledge mode will acknowledge the message when the client calls message.acknowledge().

However, if after successful execution of the message, the consumer does not find any acknowledgement from the client side, spring assumes the execution was successful and acknowledges the message.

If at any point of time, consumer got an exception while processing the message, spring listener needs to know some exception has occured in order to redeliver the message to the queue for another consumer thread to pick it up. If you're catching the exception, spring assumes everything was handled and execution was smooth and hence acknowledges the message.

Spring message listener only allows to throw JMS exception from onMessage listener. Catching your custom exception and throwing a JMS exception from listener (after logging the error for future reference) will allow you to redeliver the message.

Comment: check acknowledge section in https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/jms/message and implementation of (say) CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT  is present here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-amazon-sqs-with-spring-boot-and-spring-jms/